# Backend for python3 module matplotlib

Tags: gtk, python3, matplotlib

I'm trying to use python3 to plot graphs.

The only back-end for matplotlib that seems to work is tkAgg (Tkinter), however this looks like it has been designed in the Stone Age. So I was trying to find a replacement. As I'm using Unity which is based on Gnome and which uses GTK I thought I would use those. However I can't get any of the following back-ends to work:

```
GTKAgg (requires python(3)-gtk2)
GTK3AGG (gtk3Agg backend is not known to work on Python 3.x.)
GTK3Cairo (no window opens)
QT4AGG (requires QT4 which is not installed on my system).
```

I have installed the following packages:

```
python3 python3-matplotlib ipython3 python3-cairo python3-gi
```

I have also tried installing python3-gtk2 but that returns this error:

> Package python3-gtk2 is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source

Which I'm guessing means that I'm not supposed to use it on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Choosing GTK3Cairo as a backend throws no errors and imports fine using ipython3 and pylabs; but, it also doesn't open a new window when I call the plot() function.

Is there really nothing else that I can use besides tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on arch. But literally 2mins ago I got qtk4agg to work, I had to delete a sip.so file from inside /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ so that the package was actually installed
so set your backend in matplotlibrc to Qt4Agg remove the sip.so file if necessary then install python-pyqt4 and all should be working